# Java JSONObject error when deserializing with backslashes

Tags: java, json

I am running a Java Servlet webserver which receives the following request:

http://localhost:8080/ForVen/Recebimento/recebeDispositivo.jsp?lista={"dispositivo":[{"Id":0,"DataMod":"2021-09-28T16:55:55.3528819-03:00","SeSincronizar":0,"NrVersaoReg":1,"DataSincronizacao":"2021-09-28T16:55:55.3538812-03:00","Guid":"BFEBFBFF000206A7","TipoDispositivo":0,"URL":"","VendedorId":1}]}

When I send it, it gives me the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.json.JSONException: Missing value at character 1 of {"dispositivo":[{"Id":0,"DataMod":"2021-09-28T16:55:55.3528819-03:00","SeSincronizar":0,"NrVersaoReg":1,"DataSincronizacao":"2021-09-28T16:55:55.3538812-03:00","Guid":"BFEBFBFF000206A7","TipoDispositivo":0,"URL":"","VendedorId":1}]}

If I try to send the same request, but with the JSON "formatted", it works.

http://localhost:8080/ForVen/Recebimento/recebeDispositivo.jsp?lista={"dispositivo":[{"Id":0,"DataMod":"2021-09-28T16:55:55.3528819-03:00","SeSincronizar":0,"NrVersaoReg":1,"DataSincronizacao":"2021-09-28T16:55:55.3538812-03:00","Guid":"BFEBFBFF000206A7","TipoDispositivo":0,"URL":"","VendedorId":1}]}

This is the way I am deserializing the JSON:

```
JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(myIncomingJson);
```

I don't know if it has something to do with some Apache configuration, but I hope so, it would be extremely painful to change all of the client-side requests.

Comment: Have you tried to `UrlEncode` payload in the url? And why do you use backslashes to escape string values in the URL anyways?

Comment: It's better to use POST instead of GET, and pass your json as request body

Comment: Yeah, POST would be better, but it is a legacy app with many GET requests like this one

Answer (score 0):

As f1sh said, I have to encode the JSON that is being send on the URL, my mistake that I didn't saw it. :)

This is how the URL should be:

http://192.168.1.58:8080/ForVen/Recebimento/recebeDispositivo.jsp?lista=%7B%5C%22dispositivo%5C%22%3A%5B%7B%5C%22Id%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22DataMod%5C%22%3A%5C%222021-09-30T09%3A15%3A37.4138271-03%3A00%5C%22%2C%5C%22SeSincronizar%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22NrVersaoReg%5C%22%3A1%2C%5C%22DataSincronizacao%5C%22%3A%5C%222021-09-30T09%3A15%3A37.4148274-03%3A00%5C%22%2C%5C%22Guid%5C%22%3A%5C%22BFEBFBFF000206A7%5C%22%2C%5C%22TipoDispositivo%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22URL%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22VendedorId%5C%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).